# Solving *J^\intercal J x = J^\intercal b* where *J* is the Jacobian of a Neural network more efficient

Tags: python, pytorch, gradient, autograd

I want to solve

[image]

where *J* is a Jacobian of a neural network evaluated at some point *z*. Computing this using the following snippet turns out to be quite slow.

```py
   jac = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(network, z)
   p = torch.linalg.solve(
     torch.matmul(jac.transpose(0, 1), jac),
     torch.matmul(jac.transpose(0, 1), b),
   )
```

I found out that using a vector Jacobian product one can more efficiently compute the right hand side of the equation. That brings us to

```py
   jac = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(network, z)
   _, jac_lambda = functorch.vjp(network, z)
   x = torch.linalg.solve(
     torch.matmul(jac.transpose(0, 1), jac),
     jac_lambda(b),
   )
```

However, now I still need to compute the Jacobian for the left hand side. Is there a smarter/more efficient way to compute the left hand side?

Comment: This is a linear least square problem. Did you try the more specialized function `torch.linalg.lstsq(jac, b).solution`?

Comment: I tried that, but the difference in time is not noticeable. This is probably because  `jac = torch.autograd.functional.jacobian(network, z)` is such an expensive operation.